# Autocomplete with bootstrap typeahead in google app engine

Tags: jquery, python, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am using Bootstrap typeahead in a Google App Engine application, but its not working.

My HTML:

```
<div class="well">
  <input type="text" class="span3" id="search" name="search"
         data-provide="typeahead" data-items="4" />
</div>
<script>  
  $('#search').typeahead({
    ajax: { url: '/SearchCity', 
    triggerLength: 1 }
 });
</script>
```

And my Python code:

```
class SearchCity(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = ['cat','dog','bird', 'wolf']
        data = json.dumps(data)         
        self.response.out.write(data)
```

Why is the autocompletetion not working? What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typeahead expects the choices to be in an `options` variable. Convert your view to this:

```
class SearchCity(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        data = ['cat','dog','bird', 'wolf']
        data = json.dumps({'options': data}) #Changed line
        self.response.out.write(data)
```

Also, your HTML might need some changes, try the following:

```
$('#id_chain').typeahead({
  minLength: 1,
  source: function (query, process) {
    return $.get('/SearchCity', function (data) {
      return process(data.options);
    });
  }
});
```

Disclaimer here is that you don't specify the version of Bootstrap you are using... this is working with v2+ of the framework.

Comment: Thank you very much for answer , But am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined " error

Comment: Could you provide some context to that error, possibly a stack trace? You might have your script includes ordered in a bad way, but it is hard to tell without more info.

Comment: I am getting this error at javascript console 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'toLowerCase' of undefined new.js:205
Typeahead.matcher new.js:205
(anonymous function) new.js:192
e.extend.grep jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
Typeahead.lookup new.js:191
Typeahead.keyup new.js:302
g jquery-1.7.1.min.js:2
f.event.dispatch jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3
h.handle.i

Comment: Do you get the data successfully from the server? In other words, if you add `console.log(data);` and `console.log(data.options);` before the `return process(data.options);` line, what do you get?

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination , i have solved this problem by adding `self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'` in SearchCity

Answer (score 1):

As the [bootstrap's documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#typeahead) says this sould look more less like:

```
function get_data_async(query, callback) {
    $.ajax({
          url: '/SearchCity/',
          data: query,
          dataType: 'json',
          type: 'POST',
          success: callback
    })
}

$('#search').typeachead({source: get_data_async})
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your explaination , i have solved this problem by adding `self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'` in SearchCity